# How to approach these question

Tags: geometry

Suppose the straight line $AB$ of triangle $ABC$ is bisected at $O$ and the perpendiculars $AX$, $BY$ ,$CZ$ are drawn to any straight line $OP$. Prove that

- if $A$, $B$ are on the same side of $OP$, then $2CX =AX + BY$.
- if $A$, $B$ are on the opposite side of $OP$, then $2CZ=$ difference of $AX$ and $BY$.

Comment: Maybe I understand this wrong, but bisected means that $O$ is the halfway point between $A$ and $B$, so for any line going through $O$ that is not along $AB$, the points $A$ and $B$ are on the opposite sides of $OP$

Comment: Same thing I have doubt!

Comment: Maybe instead it would be "A line OP intersects the straight line AB at O, not necessarily between A and B". Then the problem would make sense